# Multiple lines of text with \rule?

Tags: rules

I'm editing a tex file which generates a calendar.  It works great, and I want to add text to a day on the calendar.  The calendar looks like this currently:

[image: Calendar screenshot]

Each cell of the calendar is generated with a command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{WriteBgSec}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{Black}{gray}{0}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\DayColWidthMP}
\setlength{\DayColWidthMP}{0.25\textwidth}

\newcommand{\vstrut}[2][0pt]{\rule[#1]{0pt}{#2}}

% Cell format on Monthly Planner
% - template: #1 - color for day number and left rule, #2 - date number
\newcommand{\CellFormatMPTemplate}[2]{%
    % gray bar at the top, ~ half row width
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\smash[b]{\color{WriteBgSec}\rule[0.4\baselineskip]{\DayColWidthMP}{0.5\baselineskip}}}%
    % thin rule to the left almost full heigh 
    {\color{#1}\rule[-6\baselineskip]{\arrayrulewidth}{6\baselineskip}}%
    % right-aligned date numbers
    \makebox[2.7ex]{\hspace{\fill}{\color{#1}#2}}%
    % the column is centered so force the previous box to the left
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \break%
    % white last row, makes the left sided line open/incomplete (does not join the one below)
    \vstrut{1em}}


% These calls are put in a tabular* to make a calendar
\CellFormatMPTemplate{Black}{2}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to add holidays below the day number, such as "New Year's Day", "Company Picnic" etc.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get text to the right of that `\rule`.  I'm not finding much documentation, but I suspect `\rule` doesn't support this concept of multiple lines of text inline with it?

What options do I have?  Should I do something else to draw the line?  Can I do something else to get multiple lines of text here?

Comment: Can you say or indicate with a diagram exactly where you want to put the text? Or is it that you want to put the dates slightly lower so that the rules don't cut through them?

Comment: Sorry this wasn't more clear @Andrew!  I've updated the request - I want to show holidays and similar events below the day of month number.  I can try to photoshop something if that would be helpful

Comment: There are two baiic approaches.  1) put everything beside the \rule into a \parbox or minipage the same size.  2) use \smash or \raisebox to overlap the \rule with the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for the feedback, @John's tip got me on the right path.  I used \parbox to add text where I needed it.  Finished look:

[image]

```
% Cell format on Monthly Planner
% - template: #1 - color for day number and left rule, #2 - date number, #3 - event text to show on date
\newcommand{\CellFormatMPTemplate}[3]{%
    % gray bar at the top, ~ half row height
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\smash[b]{\color{WriteBgSec}\rule[0.4\baselineskip]{\DayColWidthMP}{0.5\baselineskip}}}%
    % thin rule to the left almost full heigh 
    {\color{#1}\rule[-6\baselineskip]{\arrayrulewidth}{6\baselineskip}}%
    % date numbers and event text
    \hspace{1ex}\parbox[t]{\DayColWidthMP-1.5ex}{\color{#1}\makebox[1.7ex][r]{#2}\\\scriptsize#3}%
    % white last row, makes the left sided line open/incomplete (does not join the one below)
    \vstrut{1em}}
```